# Journal that sum up a research area

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, r, research, scientific-method

I would like to know if you know any scientific journal of economics that publishes meta-analysis, or that publish articles summary of a research area. For example I have seen in the past articles summarizing some research questions like "inequality and financial crisis" by summarizing the important papers that have been published so far on this question.

If not, do you have any website or any reference that would help me to find such thing? I ask you this because I am struggling to find the current consensus about many questions in economics and reading thousands of articles on google scholar is very time consuming.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the +1 list provided by tdm, [journal of economic perspectives](https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/jep) often publishes literature reviews and quasi-literature reviews.

The goal is JEP is to fill the gap between different subfields of economics so articles published there are often close to literature review as they provide quick overview of some topic in a way that economists from other fields can understand. Personally JEP is one of the first places where I look for summary of published literature on a topic I do not specialize in.

Comment: And also it's entirely open access.

Answer (score 2):

Here are few:

- [The Journal of Economic Literature](https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/jel)
- [The Journal of Economic Surveys](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/14676419)
- [The Annual Review of Economics](https://www.annualreviews.org/journal/economics)

Comment: Thank you! What is the difference between these 3 journals? Have they a different approach?